# Unsupported TensorFlow op: Dequantize

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Using Tensorflow 1.6.0

converting the retrained_graph.pb of mobilenet quantized model to tf-lite

```
toco --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF   --input_file=/home/sudheer_sure/r_mobil
enet/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb   --output_format=TFLITE   --output_file=/home/sudheer_sure/r_mobilenet/tf_files/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quantized.lite   --inference_type=QUANTI
ZED_UINT8   --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8   --input_arrays=input   --output_arrays=final_result   --input_shapes=1,224,224,3  --mean_values=128   --std_values=128 --d
efault_ranges_min=0 --default_ranges_max=6
```

**getting the below error:**

> Unimplemented: this graph contains an operator of type (Unsupported
>   TensorFlow op: Dequantize) for which the quantized form is not yet
>   implemented. Sorry, and patches welcome (that's a relatively fun patch
>   to write, mostly providing the actual quantized arithmetic code for
>   this op).

can any one please help me

Comment: Can you state your question explicitly? The error message is quite comprehensive and it's not clear where the misunderstanding is

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem while trying to convert protobuf(pb) file (after optimizing/quantizing using graph_transforms tool) to tflite using toco tool.

Retrain >> quantize/round using graph_transforms >> toco [Doesnt work]

But it works for me when i use the original retrained pb file as input of toco.

Retrain >> toco [work]

Following command works:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco --input_file=~/tf_files/retrained_graph_mobileNet_v2_100_224_card.pb --output_file=~/tf_files/retrained_graph_mobileNet_v2_100_224_q_card.tflite --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --input_shape=1,224,224,3 --input_array='Placeholder' --output_array='final_result' --mean_value=128 --std_value=128 --default_ranges_min=0 --default_ranges_max=6
```

Which model are you using Inception/mobilener?
Make sure that input_array and output_array is same as used in the pb graph.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a quantised .tflite is to keep everything in 8-bit. If we convert a fp32 pb to tflite 8bit using tfliteConverter / TOCO then no Dequantize layers are going to be introduced (in contrast to the Graph Transform tool that dynamic range capturing was available).

Also, an 8bit tflite model must hold min/max ranges per layer for the activations (future support per channel for the weights).

1. These ranges are used to convert the int32 out of a convolution back to 8bit.
2. These ranges should be captured through fakeQuant layers that must be introduced in the graph while re-training / fine-tuning.
3. If these ranges are not available you can use dummy quantisation but the accuracy will drop because same ranges are set for every layer.

This is the official way to generate a fully quantised 8-bit tflite. Of course tflite tool is under development and some operations are not supported.

Using the legacy path for 8bit (Graph Transform tool) we had the option to introduce print operations in the graph, capture the ranges using a calibration dataset and freeze the ranges (min / max) in the 8bit.pb model. No retrain was necessary.

Unfortunately this kind of "post-train quantisation" is not supported in tflite.